# Working with Cocoa and a worker thread

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa

I am building a Cocoa app that has a working thread that awaits input data, and when it is available - processes it and requests display update on the processed data.

I am running into sync problems since drawRect of my control is being called asynchronously with my working thread and I don't want the data to be accessed while it is being processed. I do however need that every processed data chunk will be displayed.

The only solution I see now is to use mutexes and events to make sure that each data chunk is drawn after the process function, and another set of mutexes to make sure drawRect isn't being called while I am processing data.

It seems a bit clumsy to me, and I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to the problem? (I don't want to run my worker thread inside Cocoa's main loop since it is blocking until data is available)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a modern approach with [queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of explicit locking?

It's a [classical producer-consumer scenario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) you're describing that's perfectly suited for operation queues (available on OS X since 10.6).

You can check out

- [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)
- [How To Use NSOperations and NSOperationQueues](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

The latter having already a nice example that should be an almost perfect fit for your problem.

If you want to go down to the [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) level and work with the gcd API directly you might be interested in [this article](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/) with a similar example on how to achieve pretty much the same without the higher-level Cocoa operation queue APIs.